# Firebase rules to allow delete if the document field username equals signed in username

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzUaP.png)Need help adding security rules in my firebase db. I want to only allow deleting a post if the authenticated user is equal to the username field in posts document. 
This is my posts database:

[image]

I have tried many ways to add rules but no success. The one below gives me "no signed in user, please wait"  when I try to create a document but the delete works even if the post has another username.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /posts/{username} {
      allow read, write;
        allow delete: if request.auth == resource.data.username;
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried below and now I can't create or delete:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/{username} {
      allow read, write
      allow delete: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/posts/$(request.auth.uid)).data.username == request.auth.uid

    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

I added an image of my database but it's not showing up.
Also, please see below my code:

```
        fabDelete.setOnClickListener {

        firestoreDb = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

        firestoreDb.collection("posts")
            .whereEqualTo("image_url", imageUrl)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
                for (document in documents) {
                    document.reference.delete()
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Image Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d(TAG, "HVMSG - ${document.id} => ${document.data}")
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image Delete Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", exception)
            }
    }
```

Also, if I don't have a delete rule in Firebase then Create and Delete Document work fine but I want to limit delete to the document owner only.

I added the uid field to the posts database to store Firebase UID and still anyone can delete it. Changed the rules as below:

```
    service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
        allow delete: if request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show both the client app code that isn't working the way you expect, and a description of the document you're trying to work with.  When you say "username", are you talking about the unique random UID of the user assigned by Firebase Authentication?

Comment: Where does that username "emma" come from?  If it's not associated to the UID in Firebase Auth, you won't be able to use it in security rules.  I suggset storing a UID instead, which is always guaranteed to be present for every signed in user.

Comment: I add uid to store Firebase Auth in my Document but still anyone can delete it. I updated my question above with the code sample. Thx.